# mulitple dates split to particular format in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I want to convert this many dates

> Wed Nov 13 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),Tue Nov 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),Tue Nov 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)

to

> 11/13/2019,11/19/2019,11/19/2019

Comment: Is this one string or multiple date objects?

Comment: One string only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question `momentjs`, here is a solution using the moment JS library. First you split your string, then you format each date, finally you join the string back.

Note: this will give you a warning, because the initial date format is not a normalized one.

```js
const dates = 'Wed Nov 13 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),Tue Nov 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),Tue Nov 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)'

const parseDates = dates => (
  dates
  .split(',')
  .filter(date => moment(date).isValid())
  .map(date => moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY'))
  .join(',')
)

console.log(parseDates(dates));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, if you are sure that your dates will always have the same format, you can parse them manually using a regular expression:

```js
const months = [ '', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
const dateRegex = /[\w]{3}\s{1}([\w]{3})\s{1}(\d{2})\s{1}(\d{0,4})\s/i

const dates = 'Wed Nov 13 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),Tue Nov 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),Tue Nov 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)'

const parseDatesFallback = dates => (
  dates
  .split(',')
  .map(date => {
    date = date.match(dateRegex)
    return String(months.indexOf(date[1])).padStart(2, '0') 
      + '/'
      + date[2]
      + '/'
      + date[3]
  })
  .join(',')
)

console.log(parseDatesFallback(dates));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply map the list of dates to the desired date format.
Use the `split` and `join` methods to turn the string to an array and back.
Example:

```js
const dates = 'Wed Nov 13 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),Tue Nov 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),Tue Nov 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)';

const newDates = dates.split(',')
  .map(dateString => {
    const date = new Date(dateString);
    return `${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
  })
  .join(',');
console.log(newDates);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = 'Wed Nov 13 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),Tue Nov 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),Tue Nov 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)'
const arr = str.split(',').map(a=>moment(a).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```